# Java 2d String array fill the array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

```
String[][] work = new String[3][];
```

thats work

```
    work[0] = new String[3];
    work[0][0]=" !!! ";
    work[0][1]=" !!! ";
    work[0][2]=" !!! ";
    work[1] = new String[3];
    work[1][0]=" !!! ";
    work[1][1]=" !!! ";
    work[1][2]=" !!! ";
    work[2] = new String[3];
    work[2][0]=" !!! ";
    work[2][1]=" !!! ";
    work[2][2]=" !!! ";
```

thats dont work for me i dont know where is mistake
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

```
for(int i=0;i<13;i++){
            work[i]= new String[3];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<13;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                work[i][j]=" !!! ";
            }
        }
        for(String[] x: work){
            for(String e : x){
                System.out.println(e);
            }System.out.println();
        }
```

mistake is here 
  String[][] work = new String[13][];
3->13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change

```
for(int i=0;i<13;i++) {
```

to

```
for(int i=0;i<work.length;i++) {
```

This will save you from similar typos.